# python csv.reader comparision issues with two files of different word count

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, csv, compare

Have two files

A and B [ with same 5 columns ]

The below code works perfectly fine in capturing differences , if A and B has same row count

```
newfile = csv.reader(open(todayfile,"r"))
oldfile = csv.reader(open(comparewith,"r"))
while True:
        try:
                newline = newfile.next()
                oldline = oldfile.next()
        if newline[0] == oldline[0] :
                    FailedServerList.append(newline[0])
                    FailedServerList.append(newline[3])
                    FailedServerList.append(str(newline[2])+" at "+str(datetime.strptime(newline[1],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
                    FailedServerList.append(newline[4])
        except StopIteration:
                break
```

but when if one of the file has more / less rows , then the comparison does not get the right results

I can find other ways to do this - but this csv.reader looked like a decent solution

```
What is that I could be missing or is it how csv.reader behaves?
```

the working solution that I have in place is using dict

```
newfile = csv.reader(open(todayfile,"r"))
oldfile = csv.reader(open(comparewith,"r"))
oldfiledict = dict()

for row in oldfile:
    oldfiledict[row[0]] = row[2]

for row in newfile:
    if row[0] in oldfiledict and row[2] != oldfiledict[row[0]]:
         FailedServerList.append(row[0])
         FailedServerList.append(row[3])
         FailedServerList.append(str(row[2])+" at "+str(datetime.strptime(row[1],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
         FailedServerList.append(row[4])
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of when "the comparison does not get the right results"?

Comment: @glibdud   if the two file are of diff size , it does not fetch difference towards the end of the file , may be the next() sequence in the two files does not point to the same row because of the row count difference , not sure